Group where every non identity element has order 2 is unique (without fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups)
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
The general afirmation would be:
Let $G$ a group, such that $g^2 = 1$ for $g \neq 1$ then
$$ G \cong \left(\frac{\Z}{2\Z}\right)^X$$.
I am trying to prove that for a special case, let $G$ with $|G| = 8$, such that $g^2 = e$ for $g \neq e$. Then
$$ G \cong \frac{\Z}{2\Z}\times\frac{\Z}{2\Z}\times\frac{\Z}{2\Z} $$
The idea is a elementary proof without the fundamental theorem of finitelly generated abelian groups.

I have proved that it is abelian and my idea is to use semidirect product with $H = \frac{\Z}{2\Z}$ and $K = G/H \cup \{e\}$ that i only miss proving is a group.
If we knew $K$ is a group $G = HK$ with $ H\cap K = e$ then it is the semidirect product, but both subgroups are abelian then are normal subgroups and would be a direct product.
Finally we will have to prove that $K \cong \frac{\Z}{2\Z}\times\frac{\Z}{2\Z}$.

The dupe target goes well beyond what is needed to address the special case in the OP. That's very misleading from a didactical standpoint, which seemingly is what the OP is pursuing. Voted to reopen.

The group hasn't got any subgroup $H\cong C_4$, so it can arise only as a semidirect product $C_2\ltimes C_2^2$. Show that if the action is nontrivial, then any such a group has an element of order $4$. Therefore the action must be trivial, and hence $G\cong C_2\times C_2^2$.

thanks @Kan't, don't know what to change to get it reopen since the answers in the other questions all use module theory and i was looking one for the beggining of abstract algebra so a demostration with only group theory.

Your general affirmation applies only to finite groups. There are also infinite groups with this property, and they are also abelian and direct products of copies of $C_2$.

Select $a\in G-\{1\}$ and $b\in G-\{a,a^2,1\}$ ($-$ is set-minus).
Since $G$ is commutative and $g^2=1$ for all $g\in G$, we have $H\equiv\langle a,b \rangle=\{1,a,b,ab\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. For convenience set $c\equiv ab$.
Then $G=H\cup xH$ for some $x\notin H$, i.e.
$$ G=\{1,a,b,c,x,xa,xb,xc    \},  $$
where the eight elements above are distinct.
Then
$$ G=\{1,a\}\times \{1,b\}\times \{1,x\}\cong (\mathbb Z_2)^3. $$

thanks that works, i also did something like that at the end.

The following hint may help: prove that if $a^2, b^2, (ab)^2 = 1$, then $ab = ba$.  From this, you have that $G$ is abelian and so are all its quotient groups.  Since every non-trivial element of $G$ has order two, the same is true of elements in any quotient group.  You now have a way to proceed inductively.  This approach generalizes to a theorem for $|G| = 2^k$.

That doesnt tell us what we want $G/H \times H \cong G$ is not always true and i dont see that is true trivially in here

I only meant this as a hint.  Here's how I would finish the argument.  Let $a$ be non-trivial element and let $H = {1,a}$.  Then $H$ is a subgroup (since $a^2=1$) and the quotient group $G/H$ has the same properties as $G$.  By induction, there is surjective homomorphism $G/H \to C_2$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order two.  Let $K$ be the kernel of the map $G \to G/H \to C_2$.  Then $K$ has order $2^{k-1}$.  Choose any non-trivial element $b$ in $G$ that does not belong to $K$. Then $B={1,b}$ is a subgroup, $G=BK$ and $B \cap K = {e}$.

Since $G$ hasn't got any cyclic subgroup of order $4$ (as otherwise it would have an element of order $4$), you are left to prove that any nontrivial action $\varphi\colon C_2\stackrel{}{\to}\operatorname{Aut}(C_2^2)$ gives rise to a semidirect product $C_2\stackrel{\varphi}{\ltimes} C_2^2$ which contains an element of order $\ne2$, and hence it is not isomorphic to our group, whence $G\cong C_2\times C_2^2$.
Let $C_2=\{1,a\}$ and $C_2^2\cong\{1,b,c,bc\}$; a nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi\colon C_2\to\operatorname{Aut}(C_2^2)\cong S_3$ must send $1$ to $\varphi_1=Id_{C_2^2}$, and $a$ to $\varphi_a$ which swaps any two amongst $b,c,bc$.

Case 1): $\varphi_a$ swaps $b,c$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_a(1) = 1 \\
&\varphi_a(b) = c \\
&\varphi_a(c) = b \\
&\varphi_a(bc) = bc \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
Accordingly, take for example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
x &:=(bc,a)*(b,1) \\
&= (bc\varphi_a(b),a) \\
&= (b,a) \\
\end{alignat}
Hence:
$$x^2=(b,a)*(b,a)=(b\varphi_a(b),1)=(bc,1)\ne (1,1)$$
Case 2): $\varphi_a$ swaps $b,bc$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_a(1) = 1 \\
&\varphi_a(b) = bc \\
&\varphi_a(c) = c \\
&\varphi_a(bc) = b \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}
Accordingly, take for example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
x &:=(c,a)*(b,1) \\
&= (c\varphi_a(b),a) \\
&= (b,a) \\
\end{alignat}
Hence, again:
$$x^2=(b,a)*(b,a)=(b\varphi_a(b),1)=(c,1)\ne (1,1)$$
Case 3): $\varphi_a$ swaps $c,bc$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_a(1) = 1 \\
&\varphi_a(b) = b \\
&\varphi_a(c) = bc \\
&\varphi_a(bc) = c \\
\tag3
\end{alignat}
Accordingly, take for example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
x &:=(b,a)*(c,1) \\
&= (b\varphi_a(c),a) \\
&= (c,a) \\
\end{alignat}
Hence, yet again:
$$x^2=(c,a)*(c,a)=(c\varphi_a(c),1)=(b,1)\ne (1,1)$$
No way, then, to get a nontrivial semidirect product $C_2\ltimes C_2^2$ with elements of order 2, only. Therefore, necessarily $G\cong C_2\times C_2^2$.


Or, any group of exponent $2$ is abelian.   So the semi-direct product is necessarily trivial.
